# Getting overlay to expand upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

In [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp) simple W3Schools example, the overlay starts from the top of the page and expands to the bottom.  How could I achieve the result of getting it to expand starting from the bottom of the page and then reaching the top?

CSS

```
/* The Overlay (background) */
.overlay {
    /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */    
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Black fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9); /* Black w/opacity */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/* Open */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

/* Close */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<!-- The overlay -->
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

  <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <!-- Overlay content -->
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Use any element to open/show the overlay navigation menu -->
<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `bottom:0` with `top:0`

```html
<html><head>
  <style type="text/css">
    
/* The Overlay (background) */
.overlay {
    /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) 

*/    
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Black fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9); /* Black w/opacity */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down 

the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
}
  </style>

  <title></title>

  
    




<script type="text/javascript">

/* Open */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

/* Close */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
</script>

  
</head>

<body>
  
  




</body>
<body>
<!-- The overlay -->
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

  <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <!-- Overlay content -->
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Use any element to open/show the overlay navigation menu -->
<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This was the solution!

Answer (score 3):

In CSS remove 'top: 0' and add 'bottom: 0'. Hope this helps.